# How to print Webview on a windows store app

Tags: c#, printing, webview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Hey guys i have been trying to print my Webview using the tutorial Jerry Nixon gave on [How do I print WebView content in a Windows Store App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049677/how-do-i-print-webview-content-in-a-windows-store-app) and the tutorial from "windows 8 apps with xaml and c#" by Adam Nathan, i have attached the code below from his example:

```
using System;
using Windows.Graphics.Printing;
using Windows.Graphics.Printing.OptionDetails;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing;

namespace Chapter19
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // Supports printing pages, where each page is a UIElement
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Attach handlers to relevant events
        doc.GetPreviewPage += OnGetPreviewPage;
        doc.AddPages += OnAddPages;

        PrintManager printManager = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        printManager.PrintTaskRequested += OnPrintTaskRequested;
    }

    // Prepare the print preview pages
    void OnGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.doc.SetPreviewPageCount(2, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
        if (e.PageNumber == 1)
        {
            this.doc.SetPreviewPage(1, new Viewbox
            {
                Child = new Button
                {
                    Content = "PAGE 1!",
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.doc.SetPreviewPage(2, new Viewbox
            {
                Child = new Button
                {
                    Content = "PAGE 2!",
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Prepare the real pages
    void OnAddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
        this.doc.AddPage(new Viewbox
        {
            Child = new Button
            {
                Content = "PAGE 1!",
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            }
        });
        this.doc.AddPage(new Viewbox
        {
            Child = new Button
            {
                Content = "PAGE 2!",
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            }
        });
        this.doc.AddPagesComplete();
    }

    // Prepare and perform the printing
    void OnPrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender,
                              PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        // This gets invoked as soon as the Devices pane is shown
        PrintTask task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Document Title",
          async (taskArgs) =>
          {
              // This is invoked on a background thread when the Print
              // button is clicked
              var deferral = taskArgs.GetDeferral();
              await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
              {
                  // This must run on the main thread
                  taskArgs.SetSource(doc.DocumentSource);
                  deferral.Complete();
              });
          });

        // Show custom options

        PrintTaskOptionDetails details =
        PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(task.Options);
        details.DisplayedOptions.Clear();
        details.DisplayedOptions.Add(StandardPrintTaskOptions.MediaSize);

        // A custom text option
        PrintCustomTextOptionDetails option1 = details.CreateTextOption(
          "CustomId1", "Header");
        details.DisplayedOptions.Add("CustomId1");

        // A custom list option
        PrintCustomItemListOptionDetails option2 = details.CreateItemListOption(
          "CustomId2", "Contents");
        option2.AddItem("customItemId1", "As Seen on Screen");
        option2.AddItem("customItemId2", "Summary View");
        option2.AddItem("customItemId3", "Full Details");
        option2.AddItem("customItemId4", "Multiple Columns");
        details.DisplayedOptions.Add("CustomId2");

        // Handle options changes
        details.OptionChanged += OnOptionChanged;
    }

    void OnOptionChanged(PrintTaskOptionDetails sender, PrintTaskOptionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Handle custom options
    }
}
}
```

the problem i am having is that i am struggling to get "MywebviewPages" that jerry generated onto the
    "this.doc.SetPreviewPage"
and
    "this.doc.AddPage"
from Nathans example. Due to lack of PDF api's on winRT i am forced to use webview since its the only way to have tables. please help

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049677/how-do-i-print-webview-content-in-a-windows-store-app

Comment: Hey uddhab, my problem is combining material from your link (its written by nixon) and the code above