# WebView to WebViewBrush - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I am trying to convert my WebView to a WebViewBrush in order to print it, in my UWP (C#/XAML) app.

I've set up my WebView, and the Brush such that when I click a button the WebView is hidden and the WebViewBrush gets displayed.

This is the XAML:

```
<WebView ext:Extension.HtmlString="{Binding Html}"
         x:Name="saveWebView"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="0" /> 

<Rectangle Height="400" x:Name="saveWebViewBrush" />
```

[image]

When I click the button to show the Brush, basically it's only taking a snapshot of what was visible in the WebView. What I want is to take a snapshot of the *entire* WebView (and not the scrollbars either!).

The only other person I've seen attempt this was https://stackoverflow.com/a/17222629/2884981 - but unfortunately that's a few years old, and when I try that solution I get a million errors stemming from InvokeScript being obsolete and InvokeScriptAsync causes breaking changes.

The C# code when I press the button is this:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //make the rectangle visible when you want something over the top of the web content
    saveWebViewBrush.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

    //if the rectangle is visible, then hit the webview and put the content in the webviewbrush
    if (saveWebViewBrush.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
    {
        WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
        b.SourceName = "saveWebView";
        b.Redraw();
        saveWebViewBrush.Fill = b;
        saveWebView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to convert this whole WebView to a WebView brush I'd be most grateful.

#### EDIT

To explain the "why", I am trying to print the contents of a WebView. It seems from what I have read that this is not possible, unless I convert it to a WebViewBrush. But if anyone has any alternative ideas I am all ears!

Answer (score 2):

> If anyone knows how to convert this whole WebView to a WebView brush I'd be most grateful.

To achieve this, you can try with following method:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int width;
    int height;
    // get the total width and height
    var widthString = await saveWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
    var heightString = await saveWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });

    if (!int.TryParse(widthString, out width))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page width");
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page height");
    }

    // resize the webview to the content
    saveWebView.Width = width;
    saveWebView.Height = height;

    WebViewBrush b = new WebViewBrush();
    b.SourceName = "saveWebView";
    b.Redraw();
    saveWebViewBrush.Fill = b;
}
```

Please note that [WebViewBrush.Redraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.redraw.aspx) method happens asynchronously. So to make sure we can get the complete snapshot, we'd better not hide the `WebView` or we can add some delay before hide the `WebView` like:

```
await Task.Delay(500);
saveWebView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Once we have the "saveWebViewBrush" Rectangle, we can refer to the [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39140069/6224529) to print it.