# Not able to set the width and height property in UWP print preview page

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a UWP application and need to implement the print functionality. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074684/how-to-print-in-uwp-app) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) for the same. These links helped me to setup all the print functionalities where I am able to generate a print preview page for the content to the printed.

The preview page, however, shows the image to be printed within a small block only. I am basically not able to set the height and width (or any similar property) so that it fits to the page. I have attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZVmz.jpg) and code snippets.

I have been stuck with this for quite a while. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

XAML code for print panel and UI element to be printed:

```
                           <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="myImage"

                                       Height="594"
                                       Width="432"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"></Image>
                                <Border x:Name="inkContainer"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                        Height="594"
                                        Width="432">
                                    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"
                                               Height="594"
                                               Width="432" />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                 <RelativePanel x:Name="PrintView"
                               BorderThickness="1"
                               Visibility="Collapsed"
                               Background="#eaedf1"
                               BorderBrush="Black"
                               CornerRadius="2">

                    <Image x:Name="PrintImage"
                           Height="594"
                           Width="432"
                           Margin="50,20,0,0"></Image>

                    <Button Name="btnPrint"
                            Content="Print"
                            Background="#1bcfb4"
                            Foreground="white"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            IsEnabled="True"
                            Width="100"
                            Margin="160, 630, 0, 0"
                            Click="PrintButtonClick"/>

                    <Button Name="btnClosePrintPreview"
                            Content="Close"
                            Background="#5c5151"
                            Foreground="white"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            IsEnabled="True"
                            Width="100"
                            Margin="270, 630, 0, 0"
                            Click="btnClosePrintPreview_Click"/>
                </RelativePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Register for PrintTaskRequested event
            printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
            printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;

            // Build a PrintDocument and register for callbacks
            printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDocSource = printDoc.DocumentSource;
            printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;
            printDoc.GetPreviewPage += GetPreviewPage;
            printDoc.AddPages += AddPages;
        }

        private async void PrintButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PrintManager.IsSupported())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Show print UI
                    await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Printing cannot proceed at this time
                    ContentDialog noPrintingDialog = new ContentDialog()
                    {
                        Title = "Printing error",
                        Content = "\nSorry, printing can' t proceed at this time.",
                        PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
                    };
                    await noPrintingDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Printing is not supported on this device
                ContentDialog noPrintingDialog = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    Title = "Printing not supported",
                    Content = "\nSorry, printing is not supported on this device.",
                    PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
                };
                await noPrintingDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

        private void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Create the PrintTask.
            // Defines the title and delegate for PrintTaskSourceRequested
            var printTask = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Print", PrintTaskSourceRequrested);

            // Handle PrintTask.Completed to catch failed print jobs
            printTask.Completed += PrintTaskCompleted;
        }

        private void btnClosePrintPreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void PrintTaskSourceRequrested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
        {
            // Set the document source.
            args.SetSource(printDocSource);
        }

        private void Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
        {
            // As I only want to print one Rectangle, so I set the count to 1
            printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
        }

        private void GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Provide a UIElement as the print preview.
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, this.PrintImage);
        }

        private void AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.AddPage(this.PrintImage);

            // Indicate that all of the print pages have been provided
            printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
        }

        private async void PrintTaskCompleted(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Notify the user when the print operation fails.
            if (args.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Failed)
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    ContentDialog noPrintingDialog = new ContentDialog()
                    {
                        Title = "Printing error",
                        Content = "\nSorry, failed to print.",
                        PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
                    };
                    await noPrintingDialog.ShowAsync();
                });
            }
            if (args.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Submitted)
            {
                this.PrintView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. In XAML, you have set the Width/Height of the `PrintImage`. This means that when printing, `PrintManager` will print according to the image size you set.

You can try to remove the size limit of the image when printing, or set a larger `Width` / `Height`.

Best regards.

Comment: Doesn't help @Richard

Comment: Hi, can you provide a minimum runnable demo? After testing with your code, I found that when the size limit of `PrintImage` is removed, the picture can be printed at its original size. If the picture size does not change after you remove the restriction, it may be due to the resolution of the picture.

Comment: My bad @Richard. Problem solved after following your instructions. Thank you. I am facing a new issue though. Using the same code snippet shared above, I am trying to print the image. The print command is received by the printer but to my surprise, nothing is getting printed. Any help with this?

Comment: Did you modify anything? Please describe your reproduction steps in detail.