# Xamarin pcl crossplatform printing

Tags: xamarin, printing, uwp

I'm working on a xamarin PCL project and I want to implement a print function.
In my shared code, I have a grid that contains a content view. the content view contains another grid with a custom list that contains data I want to print. as a toolbar item, i have a print button that calls in a dependency service but I don't know how to implement a print functionality for xamarin PCL content views.

The main platform is up.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a xamarin PCL project and I want to implement a print function. In my shared code.

You could implement a print function via [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) for per platform. And invoke the unified interface in your xamarin PCL project.

For the interface implementation about per platform, you could refer to the following document.

Android:[Native Printing with Android](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/).
IOS : [IOS Print Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/PrintSample/). UWP: [Print case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217865/7254781).