# Is it possible to use PrintHelper of Windows Community Toolikt for printing a WebView?

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I wan't to be able to print the content of a WebView in UWP thanks to Windows Community Toolkit. It seems possible as the sample for the toolkit says mentions a `PrepareWebViewForPrintingAsync` method:

```cs
// Add controls that you want to print
printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(await PrepareWebViewForPrintingAsync());
```

However there is no documentation nor code that explains how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451357/how-do-i-print-webview-content-c-sharp-uwp-win-10

Comment: Thanks, I already tried like this but it does not work well for multiple pages.Moreover PrintHelper in Windows Community Toolkit is easier to use.