# Print rectangle created programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I want to set WebView to `WebViewBrush` in order to add inside rectangle and print rectangle. I want to do everything on the backend side, I don't want to use XAML code.

I do this because I get blurry/fuzzy text when I get a print preview. So people say the way to solve this is to create `WebViewBrush` and then create a rectangle to print that

First I create canvas and brush as:

```
  private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView ViewToPrint = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView();
  private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewBrush wvBrush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewBrush();
  private Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle rectangle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle();
```

Then in method I assign WebView to WebViewBrush and add it to a rectangle,

```
public async void Print(Xamarin.Forms.WebView viewToPrint, string html)
        {
        ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(html);
        wvBrush.SetSource(ViewToPrint);
        wvBrush.Redraw();
        rectangle.Fill = wvBrush;
        rectangle.Width = 200;
        rectangle.Height = 200;

        }
```

Then inside print preview method I want to see that rectangle preview as:

```
 private void PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
           
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, rectangle);
        }
```

But my rectangle is blank, I don't see anything inside it. What I'm doing wrong

Reproduce the issue:

Xamarin shared project class:

```
   private readonly IPrintUWPService _printUWPService = DependencyService.Get<IPrintUWPService>();

   public void Printhtml()
        {
        
   var meta = "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=5.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0'>";
            var style = "<style>svg{height:140px; width:140px;} p{font-size:20px;} </style>";

         var  _htmlSource = @$"
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                      {meta}
                       {style}
                    </head>
                    <body>
                   <table border = '1px solid'; style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>qr</td>
                    <td>
                    <p><b>Heat Number:number</b></p>
                    <p><b> Cylinder Type Name: cylindername</b></p>
                   <p><b> Color: colorname</b></p>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                    ";
          Print(_htmlSource);

        }
     

  public void Print(string _htmlSource)
        {
            _printUWPService.Print( _htmlSource);
        }
```

Interface in shared project:

```
public interface IPrintUWPService
    {
        void Print(string html);
    }
```

UWP project service:

```
 public class PrintUWPService : IPrintUWPService
    {
        PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        PrintDocument PrintDoc;
        PrintDocument printDoc;
        PrintTask Task;
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView ViewToPrint = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView();
        private DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection;
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle rectangle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle();


        public PrintUWPService()
        {
            printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
        }

        public async void Print(Xamarin.Forms.WebView viewToPrint, string html)
        {


            ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(html);
            //MakePage();


            if (PrintDoc != null)
            {
                printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDoc_Paginate;
                printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
            }

            printDoc = new PrintDocument();

            try
            {
                printDoc.GetPreviewPage += PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
                printDoc.Paginate += PrintDoc_Paginate;
                printDoc.AddPages += PrintDoc_AddPages;

                var showprint = PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            PrintDoc = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void MakePage()
        {
            var brush = new WebViewBrush
            {
                Stretch = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch)Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.Uniform
            };
            
            brush.SetSource(ViewToPrint);
            brush.Redraw();

            using (var waitHandle = new System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim(initialState: false))
                waitHandle.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

            rectangle.Width = 200;
            rectangle.Height = 200;
            rectangle.Fill = brush;
            brush.Stretch = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch)Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;
            brush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top;
            rectangle.Name = "MyWebViewRectangle";

            rectangle.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deff = args.Request.GetDeferral();
            Task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask($"Card Stock { DateTime.Now}", OnPrintTaskSourceRequested);

            deff.Complete();

        }
        async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
        {

            var def = args.GetDeferral();
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                args.SetSource(printDoc.DocumentSource);
            });
            def.Complete();
        }

        private void PrintDoc_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.AddPage(rectangle);
            printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
        }

        private async void PrintDoc_Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintTaskOptions printingOptions = ((PrintTaskOptions)e.PrintTaskOptions);
            deviceCollection =  await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}\"");
           var rolloPrinter = deviceCollection.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Rollo")).SingleOrDefault();

            // Get the page description to deterimine how big the page is
            PrintPageDescription pageDescription = printingOptions.GetPageDescription(0);

            PrintTaskOptions opt = Task.Options;

            printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
        }

        private  void PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, rectangle);
        }

      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fill rectangle with WebView data

Derive from your description, it looks you have not rendered rectangle in the xaml before call print api. And insert it into `printDoc` pages. Please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451357/how-do-i-print-webview-content-c-sharp-uwp-win-10/46467477#46467477)  and render rectangle at first.

```
Rectangle page = (Rectangle)this.FindName("MyWebViewRectangle");
printDoc.AddPage(page);
printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
```

Update

During checking your code, I found the reason, the problem is you have not rendered your the WebView in the visual tree that make is `WebViewBrush` not work. *It's often necessary to call Redraw for a WebViewBrush that's declared in XAML in the same UI as is the WebView source.* For more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush?view=winrt-19041).

And you could use the following line to verify this.

```
public void Print(string html)
{
    // render current ViewToPrint
    Window.Current.Content = ViewToPrint;
    ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(html);

    if (PrintDoc != null)
    {
        printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
        printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDoc_Paginate;
        printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
    }

    printDoc = new PrintDocument();

    try
    {
        printDoc.GetPreviewPage += PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
        printDoc.Paginate += PrintDoc_Paginate;
        printDoc.AddPages += PrintDoc_AddPages;

        var showprint = PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    //PrintDoc = null;
    //GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: I didn't use XAML on the service. So I can't use "this.FindName", that's why I use rectangle as global variable. So I try:
 `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle page = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle)rectangle;
            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, page);`
But is the same thing. Blank page

Comment: Does it render in your current content?

Comment: If I use  `ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(html);` directly as: 
`printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, ViewToPrint);` it works, I get the print view correctly but with blurry problem, so I want to convert it to rectangle to solve it

Comment: I think the rectangle  need to be rendered before print.

Comment: But rectangle is rendered when service is called because it is global variable or am I wrong?

Comment: Could you mind share a [mcve], and I will test base on your code sample.

Comment: I can see the change, it loads the HTML on the page, but not in print preview. In the print preview is still with blank page, I mean appears that the brush does not work with rectangle

Comment: it could show the rectangle in my side. please check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRSig.png).

Comment: how??? did you change something in rectangle create? in my app does not work! can you share your current brush code please?

Comment: Sure, please check this  [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/PrintTest).

Comment: The rectangle works now, but that does not solve the main problem.. that prevents blurry/fuzzy content, it still fuzzy :(