# Print WebView with multiple pages in Xamarin UWP

Tags: printing, webview, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to print web page in xamarin forms. I am using DependencyService to print webview, which I have implemented in android successfully.

For Windows UWP, 
I referred to this link:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91163/problem-with-printing-webview-in-uwp-phone

The approach used in this is printing only the first page of the webpage.

**Edit** : 
I created an interface `IPrint` providing only the html source to the function.

```
public interface IPrint
{
    void PrintAsync(string htmlSource);
}
```

In PrintAsync function (in Windows UWP project),

```
    async void IPrint.PrintAsync(string htmlSource)
    {
        ViewToPrint.NavigateToString(htmlSource);
        ViewToPrint.LoadCompleted += ViewToPrint_LoadCompleteAsync;
    }
```

When WebView is completely loaded,

```
    private async void ViewToPrint_LoadCompleteAsync(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (PrintDoc != null)
        {
            printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
            printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
            printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDoc_Paginate;
        }
        this.printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        try
        {
            printDoc.AddPages += PrintDoc_AddPages;
            printDoc.GetPreviewPage += PrintDoc_GetPreviewPage;
            printDoc.Paginate += PrintDoc_Paginate;

            bool showprint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        PrintDoc = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

To add pages in PrintDocument,

```
    private void PrintDoc_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {          
        printDoc.AddPage(ViewToPrint);
        printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
    }
```

**To implement multiple pages printing,**
I referred this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17222629/6366591

I changed AddPages function to the following, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
    private void PrintDoc_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {     
        rectangleList = GetWebPages(ViewToPrint,  new Windows.Foundation.Size(100d, 150d));
        foreach (Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle rectangle in rectangleList)
        {
            printDoc.AddPage(rectangle);
        }                                                                                     
        printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
    }
```

You can find GetWebPages() function here.

```
    List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle> GetWebPages(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView webView, Windows.Foundation.Size page)
    {
        // ask the content its width
        var _WidthString = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" }).GetResults();
        int _ContentWidth;
        if (!int.TryParse(_WidthString, out _ContentWidth))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/width:{0}", _WidthString));
        webView.Width = _ContentWidth;

        // ask the content its height
        var _HeightString = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" }).GetResults();
        int _ContentHeight;
        if (!int.TryParse(_HeightString, out _ContentHeight))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/height:{0}", _HeightString));
        webView.Height = _ContentHeight;

        // how many pages will there be?
        var _Scale = page.Width / _ContentWidth;
        var _ScaledHeight = (_ContentHeight * _Scale);
        var _PageCount = (double)_ScaledHeight / page.Height;
        _PageCount = _PageCount + ((_PageCount > (int)_PageCount) ? 1 : 0);

        // create the pages
        var _Pages = new List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)_PageCount; i++)
        {
            var _TranslateY = -page.Height * i;
            var _Page = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                Height = page.Height,
                Width = page.Width,
                Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(5),
                Tag = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform { Y = _TranslateY },
            };
            _Page.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                var _Rectangle = s as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
                var _Brush = GetWebViewBrush(webView);
                _Brush.Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;
                _Brush.AlignmentY = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AlignmentY.Top;
                _Brush.Transform = _Rectangle.Tag as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform;
                _Rectangle.Fill = _Brush;
            };
            _Pages.Add(_Page);
        }
        return _Pages;
    }

    WebViewBrush GetWebViewBrush(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView webView)
    {
        // resize width to content
        var _OriginalWidth = webView.Width;
        var _WidthString = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" }).GetResults();
        int _ContentWidth;
        if (!int.TryParse(_WidthString, out _ContentWidth))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/width:{0}", _WidthString));
        webView.Width = _ContentWidth;

        // resize height to content
        var _OriginalHeight = webView.Height;
        var _HeightString = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" }).GetResults();
        int _ContentHeight;
        if (!int.TryParse(_HeightString, out _ContentHeight))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/height:{0}", _HeightString));
        webView.Height = _ContentHeight;

        // create brush
        var _OriginalVisibilty = webView.Visibility;
        webView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        var _Brush = new WebViewBrush
        {
            SourceName = webView.Name,
            Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.Uniform
        };
        _Brush.Redraw();

        // reset, return
        webView.Width = _OriginalWidth;
        webView.Height = _OriginalHeight;
        webView.Visibility = _OriginalVisibilty;
        return _Brush;
    }
```

Comment: You just posted a part of your code. It's hard to locate where the issue is. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it describes the problem a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

@Jerry Nixon's method worked well on my side. Since his code sample was posted on that thread about five years ago. For current UWP APIs, I just done a little changes(e.g, `webView.InvokeScriptAsync`). I also saw that you call the  `webView.InvokeScriptAsync` method in your code. That's good. But you call the `GetResults()` method, I did not suggest you call `GetResults()` method. Because invoking javascript code sometimes will take you a lot of time. You might get the exception `A method was called at an unexpected time`.

Then, I also noticed that your printing flow is a bit of a mess. Please read [Print from your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) to learn the standardized printing process.

You could check the official code sample [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) for details.

The following was the updated code of your code snippet:

```
async Task<List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle>> GetWebPages(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView webView, Windows.Foundation.Size page)
{
        // ask the content its width
        var _WidthString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
        int _ContentWidth;
        if (!int.TryParse(_WidthString, out _ContentWidth))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/width:{0}", _WidthString));
        webView.Width = _ContentWidth;

        // ask the content its height
        var _HeightString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
        int _ContentHeight;
        if (!int.TryParse(_HeightString, out _ContentHeight))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/height:{0}", _HeightString));
        webView.Height = _ContentHeight;

        // how many pages will there be?
        var _Scale = page.Width / _ContentWidth;
        var _ScaledHeight = (_ContentHeight * _Scale);
        var _PageCount = (double)_ScaledHeight / page.Height;
        _PageCount = _PageCount + ((_PageCount > (int)_PageCount) ? 1 : 0);

        // create the pages
        var _Pages = new List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)_PageCount; i++)
        {
            var _TranslateY = -page.Height * i;
            var _Page = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                Height = page.Height,
                Width = page.Width,
                Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(5),
                Tag = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform { Y = _TranslateY },
            };
            _Page.Loaded +=async (s, e) =>
            {
                var _Rectangle = s as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
                var _Brush = await GetWebViewBrush(webView);
                _Brush.Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;
                _Brush.AlignmentY = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AlignmentY.Top;
                _Brush.Transform = _Rectangle.Tag as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform;
                _Rectangle.Fill = _Brush;
            };
            _Pages.Add(_Page);
        }
        return _Pages;
}

    async Task<WebViewBrush> GetWebViewBrush(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView webView)
    {
        // resize width to content
        var _OriginalWidth = webView.Width;
        var _WidthString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
        int _ContentWidth;
        if (!int.TryParse(_WidthString, out _ContentWidth))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/width:{0}", _WidthString));
        webView.Width = _ContentWidth;

        // resize height to content
        var _OriginalHeight = webView.Height;
        var _HeightString = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
            new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
        int _ContentHeight;
        if (!int.TryParse(_HeightString, out _ContentHeight))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/height:{0}", _HeightString));
        webView.Height = _ContentHeight;

        // create brush
        var _OriginalVisibilty = webView.Visibility;
        webView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        var _Brush = new WebViewBrush
        {
            SourceName = webView.Name,
            Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.Uniform
        };
        _Brush.Redraw();

        // reset, return
        webView.Width = _OriginalWidth;
        webView.Height = _OriginalHeight;
        webView.Visibility = _OriginalVisibilty;
        return _Brush;
    }
```

I used the [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) and put my above updated code in it and do some relevant changes, then I could print all web pages successfully.

Comment: do you have a sample with that ? I am trying to do this in Xamarin UWP, but the document I am generating only blank pages (multiple though).